# Can't get Django redirect to work appropriately in a paginated view

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, request

I have this paginated view which caters for voting similar to Django official beginner's tutorial, but with pagination.

I observed that when I submit and redirect to the next page, i.e the next question, when I submit at this page (which is eq to 2) it redirects back to page 1 instead of page 3

```
def vote(request):
    questions = Question.objects.all()
        
    paginator = Paginator(questions, 1) 
    
    try:
        page_number = request.GET.get('page', 1)

        print('current_page: ', page_number)
        
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

        question = page_obj.object_list.get() # object list contains the objects in the page

        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
        # increment selected choice and save
        selected_choice.vote += 1
        selected_choice.save()

        url = f"{reverse('vote')}?page={page_obj.next_page_number()}"
            
        return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'vote.html', {
            'page_obj': page_obj,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(paginator.num_pages) 
           
    context = {
        'questions': questions,
        "page_obj": page_obj
    }
    return render(request, 'vote.html', context)
```

URL: localhost:8000/vote/ at first instant
localhost:8000/vote/?page=2 next
Then instead of localhost:8000/vote/?page=3 it goes back to localhost:8000/vote

The navigation in the template for the view works as expected but this isn't. Thanks in advance

Update: Below is the template

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- <h3 class="text-center mt-4">VOTE</h3> -->

 {% for q in page_obj %}
 <h3 class="text-center">Vote for {{q.question_post}} </h3>
 <form method="post" action="{% url 'vote' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for choice in q.choice_set.all %}
    <label for="{{choice.id}}">
        <img src="{{choice.img.url}}" class="img-fluid" width="10%" alt=""/>
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="{{choice.id}}" class="user_choice" value="{{choice.id}}"> {{choice.choice_field}} 
</label> <hr>
{% endfor %}


<button  class="btn btn-primary btn-md" type="submit" id="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
</div>


{% endfor %}


<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please share your template? It seems the page number is not passed to the view correctly, so it defaults to page_number=1.

Comment: I seem to be unable to edit my question, but I think the template is fine, as it navigates correctly, and when I'm on page 1, it goes to page 2 after submit, but now goes to page 1 from page 1 instead of the next page.

Comment: @Josh, it goes to page 2 because your view takes page_number=1 default and then calculates next page. To edit your question, just press edit.

Comment: @yagus, I have added the template. thanks. 

I'm suspecting the ```url = f"{reverse('vote')}?page={page_obj.next_page_number()}"``` line, but have no idea why it does not go to ?page=3 but rather redirects back to /vote without the page query params